# How to explain to a trainee how a computer receives external messages

Tags: http, websockets, protocol, messaging

I got a trainee in the company I work for. We are currently working on a JS interface that communicates through websocket with a C/Lang server. 
My trainee asked me a very good question this morning.

I quote :

> "I understand the system of sending and receiving messages, but how
>   the computer actually receives and forwards the message to the running
>   code".

I tried to explain how, but I failed as I don't know how to softly introduce port interactions.

The problem is that I feel that the trainee doesn't understand.
I know that these kind of questions can get stuck into the head of a programmer and make him/her more hesitant in front of code and I don't want that for my trainee.

Can someone with good explanation skills help me make a simple, yet complete, answer to this question?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: Analogy always works well. Think of a pigeon box in a hotel receiption.

Comment: Okay so i may take a everyday situation and fit it to how computer run. I ll try to write something with this idea in mind and try it.

Comment: I'd start with "All internet connections go through the Internet Protocol" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), which is implemented in almost every computer and every software (either directly, by using libraries or the OS-supplied functions). If you start with that, you can go up the stack in any direction: TCP/UDP, HTTP etc.

Comment: a system of tubes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always think of it as:

- The port is an address on the incoming packet
- The operating system has been told to put any messages coming into the computer with that port address to a particular place in memory
- The program knows to look at that memory address to find its messages
- The bindings are a series of processes in your program telling the operating system, the program etc where and what to look out for, which is why you need more than 1 to get everything working. Outgoing is pretty much the same but in reverse